# Le contraire d’agir instinctivement, de façon impulsive ?

Tags: expressions, antonyme

Comment le diriez-vous de façon la plus brève possible ?

(Je préfère ne pas laisser de proposition pour ne pas influencer les réponses.)

Answer (score 4):

Tout d'abord, il y a pour moi une différence entre une réaction instinctive et une réaction impulsive, mais j'avoue que je n'arrive pas à poser les mots dessus ou trouver un exemple où l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre serait incongru. La nuance est sans-doute fine s'il y en a une.

Pour répondre à la question, quelques pistes :

- Réagir pragmatiquement
- À tête reposée
- Réagir posément
- Après mûre réflexion

Ou tout simplement réagir contre-instinctivement, car on peut difficilement faire plus direct comme antonyme, s'il ne s'agit pas d'un néologisme de mon cru.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the nuance between the 2, which nuance is, imo, easier to detect by comparing the 2 notions themselves (& not their respective antonyms) i.e.:“agir instinctivement=agir sans **besoin** de réflexion” whereas “agir de façon impulsive=agir sans réflexion” (or maybe “sans inhibition/hesitation”). In its antonym, however, the distinguishing notion of “sans **besoin**" that I see in “instinctivement” is hard to capture & even disappears, curiously making your “Après [mûre] réflexion” & @jlliagre ‘s ”de manière réfléchie” suitable antonyms, imo, for both of these 2 distinct notions.

Comment: Pour la nuance, je propose la résolution d’un problème mathématique: elle pourra être instinctive, mais difficilement impulsive. La colère, elle, se montre parfois impulsive (on lance son chapeau par terre), beaucoup moins souvent instinctive.

Answer (score 2):

Les premiers mots (adverbes) qui me viennent à l'esprit sont :

- consciemment
- volontairement
- délibérément
- intentionnellement

Answer (score 2):

- instinctivement → de manière réfléchie, posément.

Instinctivement: sans que l'on en ait conscience, sans qu'on y réfléchisse. Neutre.

- de façon impulsive → posément, calmement.

Impulsivement: de manière incontrôlée, subite, brutale. Négatif.